# How to remove google Sign in?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am going to publish my app. The app uses Firebase authentication by user log in as well. Google is rejecting my app as below:

> "We do not allow the use of any Google API that accesses Google
> Account data (including Google Sign-in and Google Play Games Services)
> in apps targeted to children."

I tried to remove the line required for google sign in but still the app tries to suggest the list of Gmail accounts in the phone during sign in. How to remove google sign in?

This is my main activity code related to signing in and Firebase observing the user.

```
// Update authentication UI.
        final Observer<FirebaseUser> fireaseUserObserver = new Observer<FirebaseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                if (firebaseUser == null) {
                   
                    triggerSignIn();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current user: "
                            + firebaseUser.getEmail() + " " + firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
                }
            }
        };

private void triggerSignIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting SIGN-IN!");
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        // Configure the different methods users can sign in
        providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());

        //***** Below I tried to remove google sign in feature from the app 
        //providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());
        
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If sign-in is successful, update ViewModel.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in SUCCESS!");
                authenticationViewModel.updateFirebaseUser();

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in FAILED!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unrecognized request code: " + requestCode);
        }
    }

private void triggerSignOut() {
        subscriptionViewModel.unregisterInstanceId();
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User SIGNED OUT!");
                        authenticationViewModel.updateFirebaseUser();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Are you opening siginin intent somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. Should turn off the Smart lock.